# Convert table of user state changes into Login segments table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with user statuses changes like this:

| User | New state | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| joe | st0 | 08:00:00 | 08:01:00 |
| joe | st1 | 08:01:00 | 09:00:00 |
| alice | st1 | 08:30:00 | 09:01:00 |
| joe | stX | 09:00:00 | 11:00:00 |
| alice | st2 | 09:01:00 | 11:50:00 |
| joe | st3 | 11:20:00 | 14:50:00 |
| joe | stx | 14:50:00 | 18:50:00 |

Where stx is an offline state. Id like to derive a table which will show me the segments of login-logout for each user. After transforming the above, the result should be:

| User | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| joe | 08:00:00 | 11:00:00 |
| alice | 08:30:00 | now() |
| joe | 11:20:00 | 18:50:00 |

Any guide about how I could achieve that?

Using PostgreSQL 8.0.2

Comment: SQL Server is not the same thing as PostgreSQL - please correct your tags.

Comment: Correected, Thank you!

Comment: We can't see who downvoted, but you still say PostgreSQL in your question, but have tagged SQL Server. Also another downvote reason is "lack of research" - as there is no evidence you have tried anything that could be another reason for the downvotes.

Comment: Oh thank you about the tag .. I deleted postgre actually!
About research well, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was originally tagged for `sql server` and only after my answer was changed to `postgresql`
I added a comment about that at the bottom of the answer

For sql server you could do it by getting for each row

- the lowest starttime but not before the prior stX
- the highest endtime until the next stX

and then group by on that

[Here is a complete example](https://dbfiddle.uk/f9-WsuVd)

The query that works with your sample data looks like this

```
select s.username,
       isnull(tstart.StartTime, s.StartTime) as StartTime,
       tend.EndTime
from   status s
  outer apply ( select top 1
                       s2.StartTime
                from   status s2
                  outer apply ( select top 1 s3.StartTime 
                                from   status s3 
                                where  s3.username = s.username 
                                and    s3.StartTime < s.StartTime 
                                and    s3.NewState = 'stX'
                                order by s3.StartTime desc
                              ) s4
                where  s2.username = s.username
                and    s2.StartTime < s.StartTime 
                and    (s4.StartTime is null or s2.StartTime > s4.StartTime)
                order by s2.StartTime
              ) tstart 
  outer apply ( select top 1
                       s2.EndTime
                from   status s2
                where  s2.username = s.username
                and    s2.EndTime >= s.EndTime
                and    s2.NewState = 'stX'
                order by s2.EndTime
              ) tend
group by  s.username,
          isnull(tstart.StartTime, s.StartTime),
          tend.EndTime
order by isnull(tstart.StartTime, s.StartTime)
```

And it returns this as result

| username | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| joe | 08:00:00.0000000 | 11:00:00.0000000 |
| alice | 08:30:00.0000000 | null |
| joe | 11:20:00.0000000 | 18:50:00.0000000 |

**EDIT for postgresql**

I don't know postgresql so I don't know if this query will work like it is written. You may have to adapt it for postgresql, it will be possible it is just a different dialect of sql

here are some helpfull links

[What is the equivalent Syntax for Outer Apply in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47925994/what-is-the-equivalent-syntax-for-outer-apply-in-postgresql)

[How to limit rows in PostgreSQL SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133944/how-to-limit-rows-in-postgresql-select)

[What is the PostgreSQL equivalent for ISNULL()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214525/what-is-the-postgresql-equivalent-for-isnull)

Comment: that works perfectly but I made a mistake in the tag.. it was not sqlserver it was postgresql 8.0.2

Comment: @quinestor I added some remarks about postgresql in my answer